# Lubuntu won't recognize any USB device

Tags: usb, lubuntu, connection

So this is a bit weird cyade this came out of nowhere, as I didn't used to have any problem on this aspect

But in short, my system won't recognize neither my android phone nor my kindle. Zero, nada, nothing shows. My devices act as if connected to a power supply but nothing else (USB debug is on in my android phone). This is particularly troublesome as I use my phone as an USB tethering devices since my USB wifi dongle died

The devices don't show up neither on the disk application nor when usen the lsusb command

For testing purposes I connected an old Realtek USB dongle and it shows up (sadly there are no drivers for Linux..). My keyboard is also connected through USB and works fine.

It a the same cable I've been using so far, and testing with another cable the problem persists.

This was after I phone call, it could be possible that idle clicking led me to dismiss/active some kind of pop-up notification/configuration?

Sorry about formatting, doing this on my phone